# SVG Urdu/Arabic Processing in Alphabet?

Tags: svg, arabic

So i was looking that i am going to create whole new Unicode with my custom made glyph but the problem is that how to manage the Joining of letters i mean in Arabic there are lots of alphabet joined together and make a word unlike English in which each alphabet is separated from other so now my problem is that there is a Unicode define for a Urdu alphabet but very same alphabet join with lots of other alphabets how to handle it ? i mean there is only one unicode for that alphabet but one unicode consist lots of its shapes of join how to manage this problem of joining letters??

and is the answer of my Problem is in This Magic Attribute ?? : `arabic-form = "initial | medial | terminal | isolated"`

Answer (score 0):

Arabic letters change their look if they are isolated, or stand at the beginning, middle or end of a word. So a character has up to 4 presentation forms. In Unicode every one of them has it's own code and to disdinguish them the property "arabic-form" is used.

This website contains an example how to use the different glyphs from SVG:

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/fonts.html   (see example "Font02.svg")